# How would I find which version of jdk is compatible with Grails 3.2.4?

Tags: java, grails

I was given guidance that it would be jdk.1.8.0_31. However, Googling this jdk did not bring up any results. How could I be certain, and where can I find the download? The newest jdk (17.0.2) will not work with it.

Answer (score 1):

For Groovy 2.4 and below I would stick to java 8, I thinks there were some issues with java 11, some fixed in Groovy 2.5, but you will still see warnings. For Grails 5+, Groovy 3 I would go for java 11. I think better support for Java 17 is coming for Groovy 4.

Grails 3.2.4 uses groovy 2.4.7
Grails 4 uses groovy 2.5.6
Grails 5 uses Groovy 3
Groovy 4 is coming "soon" so it's not in Grails yet

Grails 3 is already EOL so I would get on upgrading.

https://objectpartners.com/2015/05/14/list-of-groovy-versions-for-each-version-of-grails/

[https://grails.org/blog/2021-01-22-grails-exciting-updates.html#:~:text=Grails%20Framework%20EOL%20Schedule&text=Grails%202%20will%20be%20EOL,EOL%20after%20September%2030th%2C%202021](https://grails.org/blog/2021-01-22-grails-exciting-updates.html#:%7E:text=Grails%20Framework%20EOL%20Schedule&text=Grails%202%20will%20be%20EOL,EOL%20after%20September%2030th%2C%202021).

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#dependencyUpgrades

Comment: "For Grails 2.4 and below I would stick to java 8" - Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we really support Java 8.

Comment: Oops meant Groovy 2.4 and below. mixed and matched my groovy/grails.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Grails 3.2.4 guide](https://docs.grails.org/3.2.4/guide/single.html#requirements), Java 7 and above should work.

If you really can't use Java 17, the latest long-term support version, I'd recommend Java 11, the previous long-term support version. You can find downloads for all currently-supported versions of Java [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

You can find and download that build version of jdk 1.8.0_31 here : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html

It should work with grails 3.2.4.

Grails 3 works with more advanced builds versions of java 8 and more recent versions of java too like java 11.